# How to reconcile lpstat -s output with lpr invocations

Tags: freebsd, printing, cups, lpr

I have a question about `lpstat` on FreeBSD-12.2.  Specifically, I cannot see the relationship between he output of `lpstat` and the printer name actually required by `lpr`.

For example.  I run `lpstat -t` and see this:

```
lpstat -t
scheduler is running
system default destination: NP4172.HAMILTON.HARTE-LYNE.CA
device for CUPS_PCL3_to_File_jbb: /var/spool/cups-pdf/pcl3/cups_to_pcl3.prn
device for laserIII_PCL: /var/spool/cups-pdf/byrnejb_hll/laseriii.pcl
device for NP4172.HAMILTON.HARTE-LYNE.CA: socket://192.168.216.52
device for NP4173.HAMILTON.HARTE-LYNE.CA: socket://192.168.216.53
device for NP4174.HAMILTON.HARTE-LYNE.CA: socket://192.168.216.54
device for Virtual_PDF_Printer: cups-pdf:/
CUPS_PCL3_to_File_jbb accepting requests since Wed May  5 11:21:40 2021
laserIII_PCL accepting requests since Fri May 21 16:13:32 2021
NP4172.HAMILTON.HARTE-LYNE.CA accepting requests since Mon Jun 14 14:15:06 2021
NP4173.HAMILTON.HARTE-LYNE.CA accepting requests since Mon Jun 14 16:12:44 2021
NP4174.HAMILTON.HARTE-LYNE.CA accepting requests since Fri Jun 11 16:16:28 2021
Virtual_PDF_Printer accepting requests since Mon Apr 12 12:42:45 2021
printer CUPS_PCL3_to_File_jbb is idle.  enabled since Wed May  5 11:21:40 2021
printer laserIII_PCL is idle.  enabled since Fri May 21 16:13:32 2021
printer NP4172.HAMILTON.HARTE-LYNE.CA is idle.  enabled since Mon Jun 14 14:15:06 2021
printer NP4173.HAMILTON.HARTE-LYNE.CA is idle.  enabled since Mon Jun 14 16:12:44 2021
printer NP4174.HAMILTON.HARTE-LYNE.CA is idle.  enabled since Fri Jun 11 16:16:28 2021
printer Virtual_PDF_Printer is idle.  enabled since Mon Apr 12 12:42:45 2021
NP4172.HAMILTON.HARTE-LYNE.CA-528 root                 0   Tue Jun 15 09:09:28 2021
```

But the printer **NP4172.HAMILTON.HARTE-LYNE.CA** is not actually recognized by `lpr`:

```
lpr -P NP4172.HAMILTON.HARTE-LYNE.CA info.txt
lpr: NP4172.HAMILTON.HARTE-LYNE.CA: unknown printer
```

If I do this: `lpr -P np4172 info.txt` then the the file is spooled and printed.  However if I do this I get the unknown printer error:

```
lpr -P NP4172 info.txt
lpr: NP4172: unknown printer
```

This host system uses `CUPS`.  I have the `/etc/printcap` file configured for `lpd` and the `CUPS` version of `lpd` is running (as is shown in the output of `lpstat -t`).  The printer name `np4172` is in `/etc/printcap` and this no doubt is where `lpr` is checking.  But this essential information is apparently not readily found using the expected tools.

This has me confused.  If I want to find the actual printer names available on a host then what is the command to reveal the real printer names that `lpr` will accept?

Comment: maybe name resolution ? what are result from  `nslookup NP4172.HAMILTON.HARTE-LYNE.CA` and `nslookup np4172` (lowercase) ?

Comment: Both `nslookup` calls provide the same response.   The problem is not DNS because `lpstat` says it does not recognize the printer name as valid.

Comment: I no longer have a `lpstat -t` available, but maybe `lpstat -t` show FDQN of np4172's IP, while *real* entry is np4172 as stored in `cups`. contrary to `ssh` you have to use official printer name (mainly because of printer option) when dealing with printer.

Comment: what I am trying to discover is how the actual printer names are discoverable by a user other than by looking in the `printcap` file itself.  It seems absurd to me that the `lpstat` command will display the printer queue name but not the actual name of the printer itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I want to find the actual printer names available on a host then
> what is the command to reveal the real printer names that lpr will
> accept?

`lpc status all` may be what you're looking for:

```
$ lpc status all
lpraw:
        queuing is enabled
        printing is enabled
        no entries in spool area
        printer idle
lp:
        queuing is enabled
        printing is enabled
        no entries in spool area
        printer idle
lj2430:
        queuing is enabled
        printing is enabled
        no entries in spool area
        printer idle
clr:
        queuing is enabled
        printing is enabled
        no entries in spool area
        printer idle
```